# AsyncTask with intent service (w AlarmManager)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, alarmmanager

I have finished building an android weather application. It uses AsyncTask to get weather from an api and updates UI in onPostExecute() by calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

Now I would also like to create a background service/task etc. I am aware of AlarmManager. I would like to know, what should be used in conjunction with an AlarmManager to trigger the AsyncTask. My concern and reason for this question is my AsyncTask is also updating the UI. However if any background service call the AsyncTask, there is no UI in the foreground as app is not running currently. Will it result in a crash?

**UPDATE**
In my main activity I call this method to initiate my alarm manager

```
 public void scheduleAlarm() {
    // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // first run of alarm is immediate
    int intervalMillis = 10000; // 5 seconds
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);
}
```

Alarm manager implementation:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, WeatherIntentService.class);
    i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
    context.startService(i);
}
```

Intent service implementation

```
    @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Do the task here
    Log.i("MyTestService", "Service running");
}
```

I am confused as to how to start the async task. As my async task is dependant on sharedpreferences and also location received from gms etc. Please guide me to the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no UI, place your `Asynctask` in a `Service` and then store your data in `SQLite` so that the moment you open the app >> you only need to fetch it from the database.

Here is an example flow

- Alarm Manager will tell the Service to Execute the Asynctask
- Asynctask will gather information from the server or your API
- The gathered information/data should be stored in SQL
- When opening the App, ask first the database for the data and update the UI.
- *Do your usual app routine*

Comment: Can the shared preferences be accessed by the intent service? I think I will have to make a lot of changes. I am thinking or switching to content providers. Will that be a better way? Because in the above flow, if the database has some data, the app will show outdated data even after manual (non intent service, asynctask ) refresh

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if you can really Access Preference in IS but I think yes, and If you are going to use SQL make sure to clear them once you open the app so that old data will be removed and besides you can add Date in SQL to compare whether the data is old or not. I hope this clear things :)